# Are questions about feminism on topic on politics.SE?

Tags: discussion

Are questions on the origin of the feminism movement, the theoretical basis for the movement, and evidence for feminist claims on topic on politics.SE?

That is, is feminism.SE,http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67410/feminism, a duplicate of Politics.SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that are on-topic relate to personalities, procedures, and policies.  I would argue that questions about the feminist movement, including their history and their claims, are on-topic.

What I'm personally *not* interested in, however, is whether they are right or wrong.  My suspicion is that there will be some overlap, but when it comes to the questions of "As a feminist, should I X, Y, or Z," those would be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, political doctrines and ideologies are the subject of political sciences. It applies to both historical and contemporary ones.

Feminism is an ideology that makes claims about the social reality, which can be analysed and prooved, exactly in the same way as the claims made by libertarianism or communism. Of course, any questions about what's just or good, requires to give the definition of justice or wellness to judge against. It's the only way to answer them in objective way.

Some questions may be better fit on History, Philosophy or Cognitive Sciences, but political sciences are interdisciplinary per definition. It doesn't make them off-topic here, but just makes more likely to become an answer on that other site.

Comment: Is a question like, are gender preferences really just social constructs on topic here?

Comment: The concept of social constructs is the part of philosophy, but when such concept has practical impications for society (in ideologies of political parties etc.) then it's the part of political sciences. However, that particular question would be, in my opinion, more fit for CogSci.SE. But Political Sciences are cross-disciplitary by definition.

Comment: Ok Lukasz, thankyou for your opinion. I will now test if your opinion alligns with the community by asking the question.

Comment: @Mew just make it answerable in objective way. And note http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/92/are-people-voting-along-political-lines, this can happen, even if it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

"Women" are a separate and distinct political group from others in society. As such, a question about "feminism," or the role of women in politics and society, would be on topic.

We might want to avoid discussions about the "ideology," of feminism (that would be more of a philosophical question), but certainly, questions about women as a voting bloc or interest group would fall under the heading of politics.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, I agree with Affable Geek. There are some "intra-feminist" discussions that would be ontopic for feminism but pretty offtopic to Politics.SE.

On the other hand, proposed Libertarian.SE was merged into Politics.SE (without parties' consent by SE dictat; which I still feel was both not cool AND a wrong decision). I don't see how feminism is any more special aside from having significantly more political clout; especially within SE employees. So for consistency's sake, Feminism.SE proposal should be folded into Politics OR Libertarian one should be resurrected as separate proposal.